# How to disable LOGS?

Tags: linux, php, hosting

My disk space usage is increasing very fast because of the logs. Everyday I get ~1.5 GB log file. How can I disable that?

Comment: What is being logged that's taking up all that space?  Is something logging full debugging info when it should only be logging errors?  Is something failing horribly and trying to get your attention?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the error log, how about fixing the errors instead of pretending they are not there?

Comment: Please clarify "the logs". Which logs? Apache Logs? Access Logs? Error Logs? PHP logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling logs is never a good idea. You can use programs like logrotate to rotate your log files if the space is the issue. If you insist on not keeping log files. Please direct your program's log directive to /dev/null

Answer (score 2):

firstly try to minimize errors then if that fails

```
 ini_set ('log_errors',false);
```

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: I should add this line in header.php?

Comment: anywhere before the errors can occurs, fix errors first tho, debugging is half the fun of php :/

Comment: info regarding error logging can be found here http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP Logs can become an annoyance when you're stuck in an environment you don't own, you're writing a CLI script real quick, and the log output insists on going right to the command line.  It would be nice if there were a quick answer like:

ini_set('error_log', '/dev/null');

Oh wait, that does work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably not about PHP, check out the Apache settings http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#loglevel

```
LogLevel error
```

Will hide warnings, and debug messages. Can be set per vhost. The next higher level would be `crit`, but is inadvisable.